# How to find a WpfCell in a WpfTable with a selected value?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, coded-ui-tests

I'm making with Visual Studio 2013 Coded UI Tests for the WPF-application of my company.
In that application we have - per example - a mask with the RadGridView from Telerik which contains a list with all users.
Because the application is still in development, i want to create generic methods.
In case of the mask with the userlist, i want to call a method, which i give the control, the cellId and the cellValue.
Coded UI recognizes the following hierarchy:
WpfTable - WpfRow - WpfText

Further i cannot see all user entries in the grid, which means, i have to scroll down while searching.
So i have programmed the following method:

```
private void SearchRowAndCell(WpfTable table, string cellId, string cellValue)
{
    int n = 0;
    int maxIndex = table.RowCount;
    while (n < maxIndex)
    {
        var row = new WpfRow(table);
        var rowIdForSearch = "Row_" + n;
        row.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", rowIdForSearch);
        UITestControlCollection foundRows = row.FindMatchingControls();

        if (foundRows.Count > 0)
        {
            row = (WpfRow)foundRows[0];
            var cell = new WpfCell(row);
            var cellIdForSearch = "Cell_" + n + "_" + cellId;
            cell.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", cellIdForSearch);
            UITestControlCollection foundCells = cell.FindMatchingControls();

            if (foundCells.Count > 0)
            {
                cell = (WpfCell)foundCells[0];
                var text = new WpfText(cell);
                text.SearchProperties.Add("DisplayText", cellValue);
                UITestControlCollection foundTexts = text.FindMatchingControls();

                if (foundTexts.Count > 0)
                {
                    text = (WpfText)foundTexts[0];
                    Mouse.DoubleClick(row, new Point(10, 10));
                    n = maxIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    Keyboard.SendKeys(row, "{Down}", ModifierKeys.None);
                }
            }
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, that i get an exception when i try to get the WpfText control because "DisplayText" is not a search property.
When i try "Value" instaed of "DisplayText" i find nothing.

Which search property do i need to find the WpfText with the selected value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found it! I need to compare the Name-property. But isn't there a better way to do this? And please, don't send a link to "http://quabr.com/25170124/codedui-search-for-grandchild-control". That solution doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the following :

```
  WpfTable t = new WpfTable();
            t.FindFirstCellWithValue(cellValue);
```

the 'FindFirstCellWithValue()' method is a wpfTable built in method

Comment: Looks nice, but it only works as long as the cell, which i want to find, is in visible range.

Comment: Usually codedui knows to scroll Wpf tables automatically to find controls - but if your table is not too big you can use this method, wrap it with a try/catch and scroll down the table on failure until you reach the bottom or find the desired cell.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just iterate over the cell contents and find the WpfText and then use string compare:

```
var cellContents = cell.GetChildren();
if (cellContents == null || cellContents.Count < 0) continue;
foreach (var content in cellContents)
{
    WpfText wpfText = content as WpfText;

    if (wpfText != null && wpfText.DisplayText.Equals(cellValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
           Mouse.DoubleClick(row, new Point(10, 10));
    }
}
```